# What is the right syntax to go through json and display the data in a view - Rails 5?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a little trouble displaying all of the values in a json response from an api especially round the rullings part where some of the values are in an array and have arrays in them.

I have had some success displaying the data but i struggle when it comes to the arrays
I have searched many related questions but many seem to focus on generating json as supposed to displaying it

Below is what I have done so far and hopefully I have made sense:
Controller:

```
class MtgController < ApplicationController
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

  layout 'admin'

  def index
    @message = "Mtg Api"

    if params[:search].present?
      url = 'https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards?name='+ params[:search]
      uri = URI(url)
      responce= Net::HTTP.get(uri)
      @json = JSON.parse(responce)
    end
  end
end
```

View

```
<% @page_title = "Magic the Gathering" %>

<h1>Magic the Gathering</h1>

<div class="search">
  <%= form_tag(mtg_index_path, :method => :post) do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label_tag(:search) %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search]) %></td>
    </tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><%= submit_tag("search") %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
  <%
  if params[:search].present?
    @json["cards"].each do |json|
  %>
  <p>
    Name <%= json['name'] %><br>
    manaCost <%= json['manaCost'] %><br>
    cmc <%= json['cmc'] %><br>
    colors <%= json['colors'] %><br>
    colorIdentity <%= json['colorIdentity'] %><br>
    type <%= json['type'] %><br>
    types <%= json['types'] %><br>
    subtypes <%= json['subtypes'] %><br>
    rarity <%= json['rarity'] %><br>
    set <%= json['set'] %><br>
    setName <%= json['setName'] %><br>
    text <%= json['text'] %><br>
    artist <%= json['artist'] %><br>
    power <%= json['power'] %><br>
    toughness <%= json['toughness'] %><br>
    layout <%= json['layout'] %><br>
    multiverseid <%= json['multiverseid'] %><br>
    imageUrl <%= json['imageUrl'] %><br>
    originalText <%= json['originalText'] %><br>
    rulings: <br>
    <%= json['rulings'] %><br>

    <% json['legalities'].each do |play|%>
      legality <%= play['format'] %> <%= play['legality'] %><br>
    <% end %>

    id <%= json['id'] %><br>
  </p>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Json Response:

```
{"cards":[
{
"name":"Ball Lightning",
"manaCost":"{R}{R}{R}",
"cmc":3,
"colors":["Red"],
"colorIdentity":["R"],
"type":"Creature — Elemental",
"types":["Creature"],
"subtypes":["Elemental"],
"rarity":"Rare",
"set":"DRK",
"setName":"The Dark",
"text":"Trample (This creature can deal excess combat damage to defending player or planeswalker while attacking.)\nHaste (This creature can attack and {T} as soon as it comes under your control.)\nAt the beginning of the end step, sacrifice Ball Lightning.",
"artist":"Quinton Hoover",
"power":"6",
"toughness":"1",
"layout":"normal",
"multiverseid":1783,
"imageUrl":"http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=1783&type=card",
"rulings":[
  {
  "date":"2007-02-01",
  "text":"The creature is sacrificed at the end of every turn in which it is on the battlefield. There is no choice about what turn to sacrifice it."}],
  "printings":["DRK","4ED","5ED","pJGP","BTD","MED","M10","PD2"],
  "originalText":"Trample\nBall Lightning may attack on the turn during which it is summoned. Ball Lightning is buried at the end of the turn during which it is summoned.",
  "originalType":"Summon — Ball Lightning",
  "legalities":[
    {"format":"Commander","legality":"Legal"},
    {"format":"Legacy","legality":"Legal"},
    {"format":"Modern","legality":"Legal"},
    {"format":"Vintage","legality":"Legal"}
  ],
  "id":"d7e1cba15888f4a6e82081a4c14123136fb9eb85"
  }
]}
```

Comment: I'm confused-why convert to json if you're rendering on the server side anyway?

Comment: Am I? as far as I know i am making a search request to mtg api and the response is in JSON. I'm looking to read the values display them

Comment: Oh I see, it's a json response from an external API. Unrelated, but I'd move that code out of the controller and into a service class-makes the controller easier to test.

Comment: thanks man I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm having a little trouble displaying all of the values in a json
>   response from an api especially round the rullings part where some of
>   the values are in an array and have arrays in them.

You have to iterate further over those arrays to get the values to display them

```
rulings: <br>
  <% json['rulings'].each do |ruling| %><br>
  <% end %>
  <% json['legalities'].each do |play|%>
    legality <%= play['format'] %> <%= play['legality'] %><br>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I have made the amendments, however I am getting an error for: <% ruling['legalities'].each do |play| %>    -   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @benjayhutton Updated! I didn't see the `rulings` has ended before `legalities`. Now it should work.